# BTS gives "invalid combination", but only when addressing memory

Tags: x86, nasm

If I assemble this using `nasm -felf64 test.asm`, I get the error:

```
; syntax: nasm
default rel
global main
 
section .text
main:
        call init
        ; do stuff
        ret
 
init:
        lock bts [initted], 0 ; <-- error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
        jc .continue
        ret
 
    .continue:
        ; do stuff
        ret
 
section .data
        initted db 0
```

Using `lea` gives the same result:

```
...
        lea rax, [initted]
        lock bts [rax], 0 ; <-- same error
        jc .continue
...
```

This also happens with any combination `lock` or `default rel`.

The only thing that assembles is changing it to `bts rax, 0`. Obviously this program doesn't have any threads, but the full one will and if multiple threads try to run init simultaneously it would definitely break.

I've looked it over several times, there's probably something stupid I missed, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: FYI, you'd normally want to use some kind of double-checked locking that first tests `initted` to see if another thread has finished running init stuff.  (Like GCC uses for guard variables for `static int foo = non_constant_function();` inside function scope.)  You don't want the expense and non-scalability of having every thread hammer on a guard variable with an atomic RMW every time.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: So like an unlocked `test [initted], 1` and bail out if it's nonzero, otherwise try the locked `bts`?

Comment: @NateEldredge: You might need 3 states: fully initialized (1), not started (0), or another thread already won the race to start running init code but hasn't finished yet (2 or -1 or something, IDK).  So `cmp byte [initted], 1` / `jne somewhere` possibly.  (or `movzx load` / `cmp`/`jne`, depending on which is better for micro + macro-fusion - `cmp byte [mem], imm` / `jne` is unfortunately not a single uop for the front-end on Intel, esp. not RIP-rel.) IDK if GCC uses a separate lock var, separate from the guard, to decide which thread actually will run the init function, but seems unnecessary.

Comment: Oh right, assuming you need to be sure that the initialization has actually *completed* before you go on.  And then I guess if some other thread started it, you have to spin or otherwise wait for them to finish.

Comment: What I have right now is `bt [initted], 1` to see if it finished, if it hasn't then `lock bts [initted], 0` to see if it's been started. If it has it spins with `bt [initted], 1` (and `pause` of course). After it finishes initializing it does `bts [initted], 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bts` has no 8-bit form, see https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bts, so you can't use it on a byte variable.

If you change `initted` to  a `dw / dd / dq`, you can use `bts`, but you have to specify the operand size, e.g. `lock bts dword [initted], 0`.

(I suppose that `bts` with a bit offset of 0 shouldn't modify anything except the low byte of its operand. So `lock bts word [initted], 0` could in principle be used on `initted db 0` if you can be sure it isn't on the last byte of a page, which you can guarantee by putting `align 2` before it.  Unless you're desperate for memory savings, it's better just to make `initted` larger.)

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I was under the impression that m64 meant 'thing in memory with 64-bit address', when it really means 'qword in memory'.

Comment: Right.  The number specifies the operand size, not the address size.

Comment: For the OP's use-case, they can simply use `xchg` or `lock cmpxchg` which do support a byte operand, with slightly different surrounding code.

Comment: I don't know why NASM would reject `lock bts [initted], 0` *with that error message*.  The actual problem is an ambiguous operand-size because `[initted]` doesn't imply one.  So starting your answer with that explanation risks implying that that was the direct cause, rather than a problem with the overall design. e.g. you should get `foo.asm:1: error: operation size not specified` like for `add [rax], 0`.

Comment: In fact, that's what I *do* get from NASM 2.15.05 for `lock bts [rax], 0`; maybe older NASM had some kind of bug where there was a default operand-size instead of correctly erroring on ambiguity.

Comment: I'm on nasm 2.14, no update available, so that's probably it. I think I had it mixed up with `setcc` so I specifically made sure that it was a byte so it doesn't yell at me. welp